# Is it necessary to apply a scale factor before band combination?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, scale

I am using **Landsat 8 C2L2** and I would like to compose Bands 1-6. If I don't apply the scale factor at all, what would be the problem? Also, when I am trying to find, for instance, NDVI value after I have applied a scaling factor to bands 4, 5, my new band'5 value is shown bellow like NDVI range. On the other hand, when I calculate NDVI without using the scaling factor I get the expected results. Why is this happening?

Scaled NDVI Histogram:
[image]

Unscaled NDVI Histogram:
[image]
USGS Website:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we always want to scale our units to the correct units of measurement. Scaling is often for data compression purposes but it isn't well suited for scientific purposes. Surface reflectance is a scientific unit and should be treated as such. You cannot substitute them for scaled values.

However, it is possible to have NDVI values outside of your expected range of -1 to 1. This can occur where you have very noisy or anomalous pixels, so the expected relationship between RED and NIR does not hold true. You may want to look at whether the pixel values in various places in your image image look right, rather than just relying on the stretch (min and max). for example does vegetation have a value of 0.4 and above? Is water around the 0 value? Is bare ground also a low value? These are general values that we would expected to see for known land covers.

Comment: I think that I have no noisy or anomalous pixels as you can see in the first image which I attached (I uploaded a new one). May you please explain what do you mean by that "You cannot substitute them for scaled values". Does it mean that, I can't apply math operations on scaled values? I still, can't understand when I must apply scale factors. @GeoMonkey

Comment: You cannot apply math operations on scaled values. You should apply the offsets and then do the math on the unscaled data. Do not use the stretch as an indicator of your pixel values. If even one pixel is anomalous, it will cause the very large stretch to occur. The distribution of the pixel values is more important than the minimum and maximum

Comment: As I understand, my first attached image which shows scaled NDVI values is wrong (because as you say, it isn't allowed to apply math operations on scaled values). I just uploaded it for example. The second attached image shows unscaled NDVI values using standard deviation as an indicator, is it a good option? Also, what is the meaning of applying the offset? What can I do with the scaled values? @GeoMonkey

Comment: The scaled values are of no real scientific use. The values are scaled because it is easer to store and move around integer files than floating point files. The values are scaled just for data storage/movement purposes. They make the file size smaller. Looking at the unscaled NDVI, you have a good normal-ish distribution of NDVI values

Comment: I understand. I have one more doubt about surface temperature factor (0.00341802+149.0). I noticed that, if it is used on Band 10 etc., the result is surface temperature in Kelvin. Is this value legit, or should I follow another way to calculate Land Surface Temperature? I am asking because you said that we don't use scaled values for math operations, and I would like to apply some math operations to my scaled band 10 (which USGS says that represents Kelvin if scale factor is applied).

Comment: I think it is ok to use the units of kelvin for this band. But you should only use math operations that are meant for temperature data. If you don't need land temperature information in your analysis, then ignore it. For example, don't try and do, for example, NDVI with band 10 as the output will have little meaning. If this answers all your questions, make sure to accept my post as the answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141054/discussion-between-chris-and-geomonkey).

Comment: Just to clarify, by saying scaled (on your replies) you mean values which they don’t have scale and offset being applied to them, right? @GeoMonkey

Comment: Yes, here scaled values are without offset applied

Comment: Just to clarify, in my images in order to compute NDVI_AFTER_SCALE I have already used the additive offset and the scale factor on Bands 4, 5. For NDVI_BEFORE_SCALE no additive offset and scale factor was used on Bands 4, 5. I found out that in order to compute it in the right way, I must first remove all the pixels that are outside the valid range (USGS gives a valid range for Bands of L2SP product). After that I must apply the scale factor and the offset on the fixed bands (without the out of range pixels) and in the end NDVI can be calculated. Excuse me for the misunderstanding. @GeoMonkey

Comment: Yes, that sounds right